# Pandas Timestamps with pytz

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to make sense of this issue related to resolving ambiguous DST transition (clock back), which took several hours of head scratching to narrow down.

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pandas as pd

timezone = 'Europe/Madrid'
# Standard datetime with pytz timezone objects
loc_dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 27, 2, 0, 0) # Ambiguous - can be 02:00:00+02:00 (DST) or 02:00:00+01:00 (normal)
eastern = pytz.timezone(timezone)
print(eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=True)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+02:00 -> OK
print(eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=False)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+01:00 -> OK

# Pandas Timestamp using built in localization
loc_ts = pd.Timestamp('2019-10-27 02:00:00')
print(loc_ts.tz_localize(timezone, ambiguous=True)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+02:00 -> OK
print(loc_ts.tz_localize(timezone, ambiguous=False)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+01:00 -> OK

# Sames pandas timestamp passed to pytz timezone objects
# ambiguous with bool seems to be equivalent of is_dst from pytz
print(eastern.localize(loc_ts, is_dst=True)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+02:00 -> OK
print(eastern.localize(loc_ts, is_dst=False)) # 2019-10-27 02:00:00+02:00 -> WRONG OFFSET 0200
```

As hope obvious, the standard datatime object + pytz timezone, and the built-in localization of Pandas timestamps all work correctly. However you can pass a Pandas Timestamp directly to pytz timezones, without any errors/issues flagged but silent failure and the offset of +02:00 returned.

I dug into the Pandas code a bit but couldn't find issue. My assumption is that this is just another of those gotchas that the multitude of datetime/timestamp variants in Python/Pandas throws up. Presumably the Pandas Timestamp looks enough like a standard Datetime object that pytz will handle it, but with subtle issues?

I'll happy log as bug but it's not clear if it can be regarded as a pytz or Pandas issue?

Comment: Not sure why you would do such a thing in the first place - I mean, `pytz` has its methods, and `pandas` has its methods to handle datetime. No need to mix them up. Side note: since Python 3.9 has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard lib, I guess `pytz` will "loose weight" over time. Not sure if the issue here can even be reproduced with `zoneinfo`.

Comment: Not something I would choose consciously. I was bouncing between pytz, Pendulum, Arrow etc to try and find a robust timezone library. I have to parse very messy data from CSV/XLS with wildly varying way of expressing dates/times (offsets, fractions of hours, incremental counters vs fixed segments etc), mixed local + UTC times, header row offsets, multi-lingual column names etc etc. In process I fell into this and fact neither library complained caught me out for a while....

Comment: zoneinfo looks potentially interesting, however I need to I rely on Pandas to_datetime() to do some of the lifting on date strings and pytz to grab DST transition boundaries, timezones conversions etc. Do you know if Pandas and specifically DataFrames with DataTimeIndex indexes work robustly with it?

Comment: `pandas` does a good job as far as my experience goes. Whenever I found a "bug", it was me not getting it right ^^ Besides `pytz`, you might also want to look into [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Afaik, all packages that handle datetime on a "higher level" use either pytz or dateutil (or both) in the background (e.g. arrow: dateutil, pandas: pytz & dateutil). In the future, more will use `zoneinfo` I guess (e.g. [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) already switched pytz -> zoneinfo).